# Isn't the intersection of curves for critical points wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Below is the remark from a textbook. I don't understand how $x=+1$ drawn parallel to x-axis and $x=-1$ also drawn parallel to x-axis. IT is a very basic thing. So I don't expect the textbook to be wrong which means I am missing something here.

[image: Below]

Comment: $x=1$ and $x=-1$ should be parallel to the $y$-axis ($x=0$)

Comment: right? So this figure is incorrect?

Comment: I think the blue lines should be vertical, not horizontal, though the intersection with the diagonal line $x=y$ will be the same

Comment: I think so too. I'm glad I wasn't losing my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you that the textbook is wrong.

$x=1$ and $x=-1$ should be parallel to the $y$-axis (which is $x=0$).

Since they want the intersection with $x=y$, they got the final answer correct despite the mistake.